# Rules for forming demonyms

Tags: morphology, demonyms

Are there specific rules / conventions at play when creating demonyms? Or are they merely formed organically over time - the most popular winning out?

There are many suffixes to choose from, but I cannot find concrete guidelines as to which is proper to use in which instance.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60464/2303

Comment: I think [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) is a good resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you have to go with what the locals call themselves. The names of foreign countries and their associated demonyms are often transliterated or reinterpreted versions of the original—or altogether fabricated because the original is unknown. As with any term in any language, the most popular wins.

These five suffixes seem by far the most common:

- **-(a)n** (mostly for countries and continents) as in *Mexican* and *African*
- **-ian** as in *Bostonian* and *Oregonian*
- **-ite** (mostly for cities) as in *Vancouverite*
- **-er** as in *Londoner* and *New Englander*
- **-ese** as in *Chinese* and *Japanese*

Other suffixes listed in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) such as *-ard* as in *Spaniard* and *-onian* as in *Newportonian* are rarer and sound a little more old-fashioned. If you need to coin a new demonym, such as for a novel, then I would use one of the more common suffixes and leave it at that. People from Earth are often called *Earthlings*, but all of the other [Solar planetary demonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Planets) end in *-an*, including other names for Earthfolk such as *Terrans*, *Tellurians*, and in Futurama, *Earthicans*.

Speaking of *-folk*, it’s best left to things with a folksy sort of feel—Tolkien’s *Shirefolk*, for instance, parallels *townsfolk*, *gentlefolk*, *menfolk*, that sort of thing.

Comment: Glasgow, Tasmania -> Glaswegian, Taswegian. Manchester -> Mancunian

Comment: -1: That's silly - the *Japanese* don't meaningfully call themselves "Japanese". I don't speak Japanese, but obviously they call themselves something *in their own language*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: …that’s why that sentence has more than one part. I’ll clarify.

Comment: Incidentally, *Japan* actually *is* derived from the same word as the native Japanese *nihon*. The Chinese version of the word pronounced *nippon(go)* was transliterated *cipan(gu)* (now *riben*) and subsequently (mis-)reinterpreted. Their *-ese* is just *jin*, the ordinary word for *person*.

Comment: Thank you for a researched reply - nonetheless, I was wondering specifically not what suffixes were available, but as to whether or not there were grammatical rules at play when a suffix is applied. As in your novel-writing example, I am looking at where a demonym would be applied to locals where no demonym had applied before. If a location's name ends with a particular sound, or even has a number of syllables, does this lend itself to particular suffixes?

Comment: @Eamonn: It’s largely subjective. If there were a land called *Purdy*, its residents could be called *Purdians*, *Purdites*, *Purdese*, or even *Purds* (like *Turkey* → *Turks*). All of these offer some clues that the land is called *Purdy*; *Purdan* and *Purder*, however, sound like they refer to the land of *Purd*. In general, I would follow common sound and stress changes: *Babylon* (Xxx) → *Babylonian* (xxXxx); *Rome* (X) → *Roman* (Xx); *Berlin* (xX) → *Berliner* (xXx), &c. Find a name that’s similar and model your coinage after it, and just ask people what sounds good to them.

Comment: *-folk* in Tolkien's writings in probably a result of his tendency to stick with words and forms derived from Old English. That makes me wonder if *-folk* or a cognate is the standard form of demonyms in other Germanic languages. I know German prefers *-er*.

Comment: "@FumbleFingers: …that’s why that sentence now has more than one part: I've edited to clarify in the light of your comment.", I believe.

Comment: -i as in Iraqi, Afgani, Israeli, etc.

Comment: Africa is not a country.  Maybe edit to say "and continents?"

Comment: @livresque: I can’t believe I have to remind people of it, but good spot, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

As you have observed, there are a lot of ways to make demonyms in English. While we can draw some generalizations for which kinds of place names (toponyms) get which kinds of demonyms, there are no hard and fast rules. The various suffixes come from different linguistic sources, though, and that has some bearing on which ones are used where. We can observe some trends:

The Latin-derived suffixes *-an* and *-ian* are by far the most common choice for English demonyms. One reason is that English names for non-English-speaking places are often Latin-derived: *Italian*, *Croatian*, *Arabian*, *Indian*, *American* (the name predates America's settlement by English speakers). *-an* is also common for Spanish and Portuguese-speaking places: *Mexican*, *Paraguayan*, *Mozambican*. The simple suffix has become the go-to for most newer demonyms, even if the place names are not Latin at all: *Hawaiian*, *New Jerseyan*, *Chicagoan*. Variations include *Torontonian* and *Panamanian*. For toponyms that end in O or U, if the suffix is true to its Latin roots it becomes *-vian*: *Oslovian*, *Peruvian*.

Some places have Latin-based demonyms even though the English toponym is quite different from its Latin equivalent: *Guernsey → Sarnian, Newcastle → Novocastrian, Halifax → Haligonian*. And of course *Norway → Norwegian*, which spawned the analogous demonyms *Galloway → Galwegian* and *Glasgow → Glaswegian*.

*-ite* comes from Greek. Few Greek demonyms have survived into modern English, but the suffix lives on in the public consciousness due to its use for nations and tribes in the Old Testament. It has become another common choice for recently coined demonyms: *Manhattanite*, *Wisconsinite*, *Tokyoite*, *Delhite*, *Vancouverite*.

Many places in Germany have identical demonyms in German and English using the suffix *-er*, such as *Berliner* and my favorites: *Hamburger* and *Frankfurter*. *-er* is Germanic in origin and is used with many toponyms of pure English origin: *Londoner*, *New Yorker*, *Marylander*, *Aucklander*; and of other Germanic languages: *Amsterdammer*, *Stockholmer*.

*-ish* is also Germanic in origin but is less versatile because it's a adjectival suffix; you don't refer to someone as *an Irish*, *a Spanish*, *a Turkish*, or *a Swedish*. Some places have one demonym for the people collectively, and another for an individual: *Irishman*, *Spaniard*, *Turk*, *Swede*.

Suffix-less demonyms like *Turk*, *Swede*, *Dane*, *Czech*, *Pole*, and *Afghan* derive from their local languages. In fact, these are not demonyms in the strict sense because they do not derive from place names; rather, they are the opposite phenomenon, wherein the place name derives from the name of an ethnic group or tribe (thanks, @phoog).

*-ese* is Romance in origin. It comes from Latin *-ensis*, which is commonly seen in the scientific names of species. It is common in demonyms for Romance-speaking places and places that became connected with Europe as a result of explorations by Romance speakers, particularly ones in East Asia and French-speaking places in Africa. These demonyms also are more often used as adjectives or collective nouns, rather than referring to individuals (*Japanese art*, *the Japanese*, not *a Japanese*). When the toponym ends in *-o* and isn't Romance in origin, the suffix becomes *-lese* (*Congolese*, *Togolese*).

Several places in the Middle East and South Asia use the suffix -i, which probably has sources in several unrelated languages: *Israeli*, *Iraqi*, *Emirati*, *Azerbaijani*, *Nepali*.

And of course there will always be outliers with their own unique linguistic history: *French*, *German*, *Dutch*, *Swiss*, *Greek*, *Icelandic*, *Argentine*, *Cypriot*, *Montenegrin*, *Edinburgoynian*.

To answer your question, no, there are not concrete guidelines about which suffixes to use for which places, except to look it up. But when in doubt, if you choose *-an* people will get your meaning.

Lots of examples from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym

Comment: It might rather be said that at least some suffixless demonyms are the sources of their associated place names, which I suppose makes many of them not demonyms but tribal names (Turk -> Turkey, but Schweizer is the demonym of Schweiz while Switzerland is the land where the Schweizers live -- a bit self-referential).  Also, saying that "Dutch" derives from Dutch is rather misleading.  The Dutch cognate of "Dutch" means "German."

Comment: Furthermore, "Dutch" is rather like "French": a phonetically altered *-ish* adjective.  It's not used as a noun.

Comment: Ah yes, *Dutch* comes from the Old English for "German" and is unrelated to the Dutch demonym *Nederlander*. Thanks for pointing that out. I moved it to the last list.