# Why is there a V in "Peruvian"?

Tags: demonyms

I wasn't aware of any other demonyms that add a V, except the unofficial *Whovian* (a fan of Doctor Who). [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#-vian) turned up a few more more:

- Barrow-in-Furness → Barrovian
- Oamaru → Oamaruvian
- Oslo → Oslovian
- Peru → Peruvian
- Warsaw → Varsovian
- Waterloo → Waterluvian

Judging from the switch from W to V in *Varsovian*, I'm guessing this has something to do with Latin, but the places in that list don't seem to be linked by a Latin sphere of influence. Why do some demonyms add a V?

Comment: *Peru* and *Waterloo* stand out because *orthographically* we don't see a **w** at the end of the noun form, but phonologically it's the same as *Harrow, Shaw (=Harrovian, Shavian)*. That's to say we always change the **w** to a **v** - my guess being that it's easier to articulate, but what do I know?

Comment: @FumgleFingers: *Togo* is *Togolese*, where we change the **w** to an **l** instead.

Comment: I think "Varsovian" may be unrelated  to the others -- note that <w> is pronounced /v/ in Polish. Also, v-insertion is not 100% restricted to demonyms; consider e.g. "Monrovia". But, +1 -- this is a really interesting question!

Comment: @Peter: Now that you mention it, also *Congolese*, and doubtless others. I wonder if those "non-standard" ones have anything in common *not* shared by OP's examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules for forming demonyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61765/rules-for-forming-demonyms)

Comment: It is a Latinization. The places aren't linked by a Latin sphere of influence; the terms are linked by using a Latinate suffix (*-ian*).

Comment: Yeah, basically if you're going to form the word by appending "-ian" you need to insert a consonant sound after a word ending with the 
oh" or "ooo" sound in order for it to be reasonably pronounceable.  "V" works better in this regard than, say, "K".

Comment: Seems 'V' has a deep bonding with long 'O', or 'U' or, for that matter, 'W'. But, Oh! Pity me. I know little of phonetics.

Comment: There's one word that shows an analogous alternation of y and j: Troy, Trojan

Comment: @sumelic - Yeah, if you intend to post-pend "-an" then a "J" sound is more appropriate.  Try "J" with the "-ian" words and "V" with the "-an" words, though, and I think you will see the existing pairings are smoother-sounding.

Comment: And then we have the Moscovites...

Comment: Moscow used be known as *Moscovia* in Latin and *Muscovy* in English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duchy_of_Moscow#Name

Comment: A related example is *Monroe* → *Monrovia*.

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peru) gives the etymology as *Piruw* [pɪɾʊw], from Quechua, the Inka language.
That [w] at the end would become a /v/ in Spanish when adding a suffix to produce *Peruviano*.

English demonyms have lots of odd features, and this isn't even English demonymy.
I remember when I was in grad school we used to try to figure out what kind of process
could possibly produce *Glaswegian* from *Glasgow*, and *Norwegian* from *Norway*.

Comment: Latinization (norvegicus) is often to blame. *Liverpudlian* started as a donnish joke; going right over the heads of 99% of the population, it became the official term.

Comment: @TimLymington 'going right over the heads of 99% of the population' Were there more Diddymen in those days?

Comment: @John Lawler Is *peruviano* an archaic Spanish form? The modern Spanish is *peruano*.

Comment: @SamKauffman Spanish has three denonyms for Peru: *peruano, peruviano, perulero*. The latter two fell out of use around 1800.

Comment: As an adjective for the works or style of George Bernard Shaw, I've seen "Shavian". I'm unsure how it's pronounced.

Comment: The Online Etymological Dictionary has, for "Norwegian", " from Medieval Latin Norvegia "Norway," from Old Norse Norvegr". https://www.etymonline.com/word/Norwegian

Comment: I'm supposing "Varsovian" is from French "varsovien", with the French name for Warsaw being Varsovie. Unless it was Varsovia in Latin and English borrowed out directly from there.

Comment: In Spanish is simply PERUANO. Not PeruViano.