# Washingtonians vs New Yorkers

Tags: adjectives

I just heard the conference held in Washington due to the roit in the Congress Capitol

The mayor referred to the people who live in Washington as Washingtonians

and I remember people who live in New York are caller New Yorkers.

Similarly in Australia, people of Melbourne are Melbournians

but people of Syndey are Syndeysiders?!!

What is the rule of using -ian, -er, or -siders? for the people belong to a city?

Comment: I don't think there is a rule. It's probably usage.

Comment: People from Liverpool are Liverpudlians. That always makes me smile.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, a "puddle" is a small "pool".

Comment: @RayButterworth thank you, that's why it makes me smile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules for forming demonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61765/rules-for-forming-demonyms)

Comment: @WeatherVane My great-auntie from Liverpool  (b. 1917) distinctly disliked that term "Liverpudlians"...she was a Frasier, from the meat-packing plant.

Comment: @Cascabel did she pack baconers, porkers, or hamsters?

Comment: Erm..no, her family founded the plant. She was a Frazier before marrying the Guatemalan vice-counselor  to the Court of   whatever it was at the time at the time of the coronation  QE II...is this going somewhere? @WeatherVane Don't diss my fam.

Answer (score 2):

Such names are known as a [Demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym).

Here are a few more:

- Mancunians are from Manchester.
- Guelphites are from Guelph.
- Aberdonians are from Aberdeen.
- Glaswegians are from Glasgow.
- Minneapolitans are from Minneapolis.
- Burqueños are from Albuquerque.
- Waterluvians are from Waterloo.
- Flemish are from Flanders.

The rule is that there is no rule.

You have to look up what each city has decided to call its citizens.

Comment: Ever since two of my children moved to Nashville, I've called them Nashvillains.