# What is the demonym for a person from Gouda?

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

In Dutch the demonym for a person from Gouda is *Gouwenaar*. What is the demonym for that person in English?

Comment: Possible dupe or at least related: [Rules for forming demonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61765/rules-for-forming-demonyms)

Comment: Most English speakers aren't even aware that there's a Dutch town? city? called Gouda any more than they're aware of a town or city called Edam, and even fewer of them would call it "Houda". Because of that there isn't going to be an established English demonym.

Comment: @BoldBen So when writing fiction taking place in Gouda, what would be the best way to refer to someone from that town?

Comment: "a person from Gouda" would be a very clear way to refer to someone from that town.

Comment: @BoldBen Well, see the cheese, see the town. :)

Comment: English and Dutch are relatively closely related.  It would be interesting to know whether the *-aar* suffix in Dutch has an English cognate.

Comment: English adopts lots of foreign words, and some people insist that such words should be modified according to the rules of the original language (e.g. "It's _stimuli_, not _stimuluses_!"), so maybe the proper term should be _Gouwenaar_. I occasionally hear English speakers refer to the people of Quebec as _Quebecois_.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Something to consider but wonder if using "Gouwenaar" might produce unnecessary confusion in a reader of a story set in Gouda.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, "a person from Gouda" is an option, but may not be the most effective in a piece of fiction. To me a more concise means of referring to a resident of Gouda would be preferable.

Comment: @Bob516 I suppose it might be a good idea to introduce the word in a way that makes its meaning obvious, e.g. "Why did you decide to stay in Gouda instead of relocating to New York like you always dreamed?" "Because I realized that I had more in common with the average _Gouwenaar_ than I did with the average New Yorker."

Comment: @DoctorDestructo That might work if I can find a context for such an introduction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would go with ***Goudan.****

There does not appear to be an *established* English demonym to describe the people of Gouda, let alone the adjective to describe anything coming from that province.

**However, I think many linguists consider demonyms to be productive i.e. *open to new formations*.**

Demonyms are often based on the adjective form of the noun, and typical examples derive from Proper Noun to Adjective conversion .

### **Continents:**

- America   > American
- Asia      > Asian
- Africa    > African
- Australia > Australian

### Countries:

- Moldavia  > Moldavian
- Australia > Australian
- Austria   > Austrian
- Bolivia   > Bolivian
- Bulgaria  > Bulgarian
- Jamaica   > Jamaican
- Kenya     > Kenyan
- Korea     > Korean
- Liberia   > Liberian
- Russia    > Russian
- Venezuela > Venezuelan
- Tonga     > Tongan

etc

### American States:

- California   > Californian
- Virginia     > Virginian
- Dakota       > Dakotan

etc.

### American Cities:

- Philadelphia > Philadelphian

---

**I have at least** [several dozen more examples](https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-countries-1993160)...but as you can see, these types of nouns end with either the phoneme /Ə/ or the diphthong /IƏ/**

No matter how you pronounce [Gouda](https://www.delish.com/food-news/a49472/youve-been-saying-gouda-wrong-this-whole-time/), the final syllable is /Ə/, in other words, a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)

**If we accept that this is a productive process, than the suffix '-an' seems to be the way to go.**

---

On the other hand, it has been pointed out by @Mitch and @Andrew Leach that there are other formations based on a similar pronunciation and intonation.

China     > Chinese

Ghana     > Ghanaian***

Malta     > Maltese

These seem to be outliers of morphological trends, not uncommon in English.

---

*In the last 100 years or so, the production of English demonyms with non-Latin roots  tends to lean towards '-an'...

**Most city, state, and nation names in English that end in a vowel usually derive from a non-English source.

***See below comments for clarification

Comment: The closest examples in accent and vowels to Gouda to generalize would be Cuba, China, Ghana, Malta, Tonga. so... Goudan, Goudese, or  Goudaian.

Comment: @Mitch Of course I considered all of those over the last hours, ( the final syllable is /Ə/, in other words, a schwa) I was looking for a generalization. ...you gonna post, or can I use those examples?...I kinda got bored looking for all the examples to support that idea...

Comment: Hi @Mitch Lovely to hear from you again...been a while.

Comment: Hey Cascabel. Yes, still here! Yes, those were extra examples for you to include in your example supporting 'Goudan'. I couldn't find any cities at all with the pattern. Please or not at your discretion. My personal preference would be Goudwegian but that's me just being weird.

Comment: @Mitch God forbid anyone should call you weird...let alone the English language...

Comment: Gouda is not a country. Some regions or cities, take **er** as in Londoner, New Yorker, Berliner.  And frankly, as Gouda is Dutch, why should it have one in English?? And even many English places don't have one. There are some unusual ones: Person from Los Angeles, Angelinos or Moscovites for Moscow.

Comment: My Dutch friend says ' "Goudaner" is possible. They are often stereotyped as being poor, and indeed [this native](https://witchwithaview.com/2015/12/17/thursday-doors-gouda-doors-with-a-history/) says "But: being a Goudaner means that I have to beg something… So please come to Gouda when visiting Holland and pay a visit!"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, maybe in Dutch and invented for purposes of that blog or whatever. Who knows Rio de Janeiro? **Carioca**. Ha ha. São Paulo, Paulista, invariables.

Comment: It's *Ghanaian,* where the suffix is extended, but still added to *Ghana.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach: “Ghanan” is, per wiktionary, a non-standard alternative to “Ghanaian”.

Comment: @KrazyGlew That may well be so, but not *Ghanian,* which is what my comment was about.

Comment: I have never heard Tonganese used for the demonym of Tonga (it’s always been “Tongan”). Now admittedly I haven’t known *that* many Tongans, so I’d hesitate to say that it’s not an alternative or something… but Google counts a bare few thousand hits for the former versus millions for the latter.

Comment: @TimPederick Yeah...good catch. I thought about that overnight, and I will change Tonga to the 'an' heap. For me, posts are always a work in progress, as we need to constantly update this amoebic beast. Insightful  contributions such as yours are always appreciated. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure there isn't one. We have our own demonyms for a few very well-known foreign cities (Roman, Parisian) but not for the majority of places. I don't even know of many for places in the UK.

Comment: Yeah, it’s hard to keep track of all the Manx in Man, Welsh in Wales, Loiners in Leeds, Exonians in Exeter, Cornish in Cornwall, Paludians in Slough, Orcadians in Orkney, Ludensians in Louth, Giernesi in Guernsey, Dundonians in Dundee, Cestrians in Chester, Haligonians in Halifax, Glaswegians in Glasgow, Silhillians in Solihull, Salopians in Shrewsbury, Aberdonians in Aberdeen, Wintonians in Winchester, Sennockians in Sevenoaks, Mancunians in Manchester, Maxonians in Macclesfield, Cantuarians in Canterbury, Novocastrians in New Castle, Liverpudlians in Liverpool, Cantabrigians in Cambridge. :)

Comment: @tchrist 'Salopian'? That sounds almost like a slur.

Comment: And those poor Novocastrians!

Comment: @tchrist - Wow, you know a lot more of them than I do! I'm a Derbeian myself.

Comment: @Mitch - Actually Salop is an alternative name for the whole county of Shropshire, not just Shrewsbury.

Comment: @tchrist It sounds like names of ancient biblical nations like Galatians or Philistines.

Answer (score 0):

"Person from Gouda".

This is the most effective way, not because it is the shortest possible (although it is pretty short), but because it is the easiest to understand. If the goal is to be clearly understood, then the most effective term is the one that can be understood easiest.

Using "Goudan" or "Gouwenaar" might be understood *in context*.  But "person from Gouda" can be understood by anyone who knows that "Gouda" is a town.

It is more effective to write "Jul was from Gouda", that to write "Jul was Goudan".  The second sentence is more likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: I'm writing in the context of residents talking to a stranger who is visiting Gouda. Which would sound more natural in English language fiction? "We people of Gouda resent your talking down to us" or "We Goudans resent your talking down to us."  Yes, if a character from Gouda was in another city, and there was no information given about the character writing Goudan might be confusing.

Comment: "You aren't from Gouda and we resent you talking down to us"   - I think using "Goudans" sounds a little silly in your examples.  Suppoe the town was "Little-Whinging-on-the-Hill"    Do you think "Little-Whinging-on-the-Hillians" would be the right way to go?

Comment: I was just giving an off the top of my head example, not meant to be a well thought out sentence. Does it all come down to a matter of taste? Is Goudan any sillier than Liverpudlian?